# setTimeout causes wrong page to loaded after sign up, update - compile problem

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

When a user signs up, the home page gets loaded (student-home.handlebars);

If a navigate to the messages page i have set a timeout on the update compile because i have to wait for firebase to load in the messages.

However, this timeOut causes a bug:
when i sign up, the homepage renders and in one second (after the timeOut of 1000ms) i get automatically navigated to student-messages.handlebars.

This only happens with this timeOut being set, but should actually not be possible because the student-home.handlebars doesn't read any code from the student-messsages.handlebars.

Help please!

```
const firebaseInstance = require('firebase');

// Initialize Firebase

let instance = null;

const initFirebase = () => {
  instance = firebaseInstance.initializeApp(config);
};

const getInstance = () => {
  if (!instance) {
    initFirebase();
  }
  return instance;
};
export {
  initFirebase,
  getInstance,
};


import {
  getInstance
} from '../firebase/firebase';
const firebase = getInstance();

const database = firebase.database();
const ref = 
database.ref('messages/').orderByChild('receiver').equalTo(currentUserKey);

    ref.on("value", function (snap) {
      snap.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        let data = childSnapshot.val();
        if (data.receiver === currentUserKey) {
          Message = {
            content: data.content,
            sender: data.senderName,
            senderKey: data.senderKey,
            receiver: currentUserKey,
            date: data.date
          }
        }
        messageList.push(Message);
        // console.log(messageList);
      });
    });

export default () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
          // Return the compiled template to the router
          update(compile(studentMessagesViewTemplate)({
            messageList
          }));
          let messageDetail = document.querySelectorAll('.messages-list');
          for (let i = 0; i < messageDetail.length; i++) {
            messageDetail[i].id = "messageDetail" + i;
            messageDetail[i].addEventListener('click', showDetail);
          };
          // firebase logout at buttonclick
          const btnLogout = document.querySelector('.btnLogout');
          btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e => {
            firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
              window.location.replace('#/');
            });
          });
        }, 1000);
}
```

//// homepage after log in or sign up

```
{{> header }}
<div class="content-lv">
    <div class="just-a-box-lv">
        <div class="toggleViews">
            <button id="toggleGameView">Game</button>
            <button id="toggleMapView">Map</button>
        </div>
        <button id="sortByDistance">In jouw buurt</button>
        <h2>Beschikbare kamers</h2>
        {{#each allRooms }}
        <div class="info-list" id="regularInfoList">
            <h5 class="card-room-type-lv">{{ this.type }}</h5>
            <div class="info-list-img">
                <img src="{{ this.image }}" class="room-picture-list" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="info-list-text">
                <div class="sub-div">
                    <p class="card-titles-lv width"></p>
                    <p class="card-values-lv card-surface">{{ this.surface }} m²</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-div">
                    <p class="card-titles-lv distance"></p>
                    <p class="card-values-lv card-distance">{{ this.distance }} km</p>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-div">
                    <p class="card-titles-lv price"></p>
                    <p class="card-values-lv card-price">€ {{ this.rentalPrice }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{else}}
        <p style="text-align:center">Nog geen koten om weer te geven</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
{{> footer }}
```

Comment: can you include your firebase code please?

Comment: There you go, i added the firebase code!

Comment: Can you add your firebase script.. it probably just needs to be awaited or promisified if it isn't already

Comment: Like this? i added what happens in firebase.js

Comment: What does your homepage `.html` look like? It might help to see the homepage code and how you navigate to the messages route

Comment: There you go, i added it

Comment: I was looking for a `script` tag somewhere on the homepage - doesn't seem to be there. Strange that you are being redirected without any scripts running